# Playing stereo wav file in android

Tags: android, audio

I am playing a stereo wav file in android in my application using SoundPool in a infinite loop.

I am changing the left right channel sound using setVolume, every one second like

```
int looper = 0;

timerhandler()
{
 if(looper == 0)
 {
  soundPool.setVolume(sid, 0, 1) ;
  looper = 1;
 }
 else
 {
  soundPool.setVolume(sid, 1, 0) ;
  looper = 0; 
 }
}
```

Its working fine in emulator. but on device not getting stereo effect.

Can somebody help what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that "the device" only has a single (mono) output?